# Counting combination of multiple variable frequency in SAS

Tags: sas

This question is an expansion of this one : [SAS: Create a frequency variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652059/sas-create-a-frequency-variable)

The code provided in the first response work well, but what if I want to add another categorical variable ? I have a date variable and an ID, categorical variable. I've tried multiple things, but here's what seemed the most logical to me (but doesn't work):

```
data work.frequencycounts;
 do _n_ =1  by 1 until (last.Date);
   set work.dataset;
   by Date ID;
   if first.Date & first.ID then count=0;
   count+1;
 end;
 frequency= count;
 do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.Date);
   set work.dataset;
   by Date ID;
   output;
 end;
run;
```

Should I add a do loop ?
Thanks for your help.

Edits:
Example of what I have:

```
Date ID 
1 19736 H-3-10  
2 19736 H-3-12 
3 19737 E-2-10 
4 19737 E-2-10
```

Example of what I want:

```
Date ID Count
1 19736 H-3-10  1
2 19736 H-3-12  1
3 19737 E-2-10  2
4 19737 E-2-10  2
```

Comment: Good point, I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired output.

What is happening here is that you need to use the *last* variable in the BY statement for everything with `first.`/`last.` processing.  If you need to know why, put a few `put _all_;` in the datastep to see what is what value at different points.  You shouldn't check for `first.Date` at any point, because if `first.Date` is true then `first.ID` is always true (by definition, `first` propagates rightwards); and you want a different count for [`first.ID` and not `first.date`].

Basically, treat the initial example as correct, and the variable in the initial example should be the last variable in your `by` statement; add as many additional variables as you want to the left of it, and nothing will change.  This does require the data be sorted by the by-group variables.

```
data have;
input date id $;
datalines;
19736 H-3-10  
19736 H-3-12 
19737 E-2-10 
19737 E-2-10 
;;;;;
run;

data work.want;
 do _n_ =1  by 1 until (last.ID);  *last.<last variable in by group>;
   set work.have;
   by Date ID;
   if first.ID then count=0; *first.ID is what you want here.;
   count+1;
 end;
 frequency= count;   *this is not really needed - can use just the one variable consistently;
 do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.ID);  *again, last.<last var in by group>;
   set work.have;
   by Date ID;
   output;
 end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding explanations concernin first. and last.